# Evaluating a Contour Integral $\int_{z_0}^z$ using Residues

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

*Introduction:* I am presently wondering about how the integral over a linear Contour from the point ${z}_{{{0}}}$ to ${z}$ could be evaluated using the theory of residues. I have had some prior exposure to the concept for the simplified case of an integral of an even function over $\mathbb{R}_+$ using Jordan's method.

*A Discussion of Jordan's Method:* I assume that any even function can be mirrored across the imaginary axis and that ${\int_{{-\infty}}^{{\infty}}}{f{{\left({x}\right)}}}{d}{x}={2}{\int_{{{0}}}^{{\infty}}}{f{{\left({x}\right)}}}{d}{x}$. Secondly, I impose an upper bound ${M}$ on the function ${f}$ over ${R}{e}^{{{i}{\theta}}}$ to ensure that the following relationship holds.

$$\oint_{{{C}}}{f{{\left({z}\right)}}}{d}{z}={\int_{{-{R}}}^{{{R}}}}{f{{\left({x}\right)}}}{d}{x}+\int_0^{2 \pi}{f{{\left({R}{e}^{{{i}{\theta}}}\right)}}}{d}{\theta}={2}{\pi}{i}\sum_{{{z}_{{{0}}}\in{\mathbb{{{C}}}}_{{+}}}}\operatorname{Res}_{z=z_0}{f{{\left({z}\right)}}}$$

$$\lim_{{{R}\to\infty}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{f{{\left({R}{e}^{{{i}{\theta}}}\right)}}}{d}{\theta}\le{\pi}{M}{R}$$

We take $\lim_{{{R}\to\infty}}{M}{\left({R}\right)}={0}$ and in particular ${M}{\left({r}\right)}\in{\mathcal{{{O}}}}{\left({R}^{{-{p}}}\right)}$ where ${p}>{1}$.

*Qualifying Aside:* I have privately arrived at a negative result, but I feel that it is best to ask a larger audience for possible approaches before reaching anything conclusive.

*Question:* ${f{{\left({z}\right)}}}$ is a meromorphic function in the upper half of the complex plane ${\mathbb{{{C}}}}_{{+}}$ defined to have a finite number of singularities that are all poles of order ${m}$. If ${z}_{{{0}}},{z}\in{\mathbb{{{C}}}}_{{+}}$ could the following integral be evaluated in terms of residues (i.e., the Cauchy Residue Theorem or a residue at infinity)?

$${\int_{{{z}_{{{0}}}}}^{{{z}}}}{f{{\left({z}\right)}}}{d}{z}$$

*Remark:* If ${\left|{z}-{z}_{{{0}}}\right|}\to\infty$ in that the line segment becomes a line, I feel that it is a trivial extension of Jordan's method. In the event that a finite line segment is used, the collapsing bound of the integrand over the semicircular region no longer applies.

Comment: Yes it can be evaluated in therms of residues, but it won't help you if the integral over the extension of the contour cannot be estimated. (Also this question is not suited for MathOverflow.)